# tsconfig short paths not working in vs code

Tags: angular, typescript

I have setup my angular project like this:

https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/shorten-typescript-imports-in-an-angular-project/

But it doesn't appear to be working.
My **tsconfig** looks like this:

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "es2015",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
      "@data/*": ["src/app/core/data/*"],
      "@constants/*": ["src/app/core/constants/*"],
      "@models/*": ["src/app/core/models/*"],
      "@services/*": ["src/app/core/services/*", "src/app/core/sessions/*"],
      "@shared/*": ["src/app/shared/*"]
    }
  }
}
```

I have painstakingly gone through my entire application and replaced all the "long" paths with these new ones and when I try to do an `ng serve` I get loads of errors.

Here are a couple:

> ERROR in src/app/categories/categories.component.ts(3,31): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@constants/animations'.
>
> src/app/core/components/animations/animations.component.ts(3,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@constants/animations'.
>
> src/app/core/components/animations/animations.component.ts(4,34): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/animation.service'.
>
> src/app/core/components/spinner/spinner.component.ts(3,32): error TS2307: Cannot find module '@services/loading.service'.

There are loads and when I look at the actual components/modules the intellisense shows no issues.
Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: I usually put those `paths` in `tsconfig.app.json`, perhaps try putting it in there? Though I don't think it will make a difference since `tsconfig.app.json` extends `tsconfig`. Worth a try.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was simply to do with the **basePath**. It should be set to "src".
So now, it looks like this:

```
"baseUrl": "src",
"paths": {
  "@data/*": ["app/core/data/*"],
  "@constants/*": ["app/core/constants/*"],
  "@models/*": ["app/core/models/*"],
  "@services/*": ["app/core/services/*", "app/core/sessions/*"],
  "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
}
```